# Buildozer compilation ERROR: No matching distribution found for hostpython2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am new to Kivy and trying to compile a simple app into an Android apk using Buildozer on Ubuntu Linux 18.04. However, I am stuck at the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hostpython2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hostpython2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

The buildozer.spec file lists the requirements:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,android,kivmob,hostpython2,jnius
```

I tried the following:

```
python3 -m pip install hostpython2
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/hostpython2/
```

Tried to upgrade Buildozer:

```
pip3 install -U buildozer
```

Already the latest version. The same error persists.

Please help to resolve this issue. I am unable to compile the apk. Trying for the last 2 days but getting a lot of errors at every step.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `hostpython2` requirement?

Comment: I haven't tried that. It was part of the requirements for KivMob. However, I think I noticed that hostpython3 has been installed as part of the compile process.

Comment: I was trying to test if KivMob works with Kivy for displaying Google Ad Mob on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"hostpython2" is deprecated. Removed it from the requirements specified in the buildozer.spec file and included "python3" instead which led to the compilation of "hostpython3". Recompiled the code and successfully overcame this step.